# Desktop REST client using jersey jaxb use on Android

Tags: android, rest, jaxb, jersey, jackson

I found similar questions are asked here, but still feel little bit confused with what I think extra complexity :(

Some solutions suggest to do some extra work and repackaging to use jersey jaxb framework on Android but somehow I have this feeling that in general  jersey is something "too heavy" for simple tasks in Android.

What I want to do is too use some "Android compatible" lighter approach to replace jersey+jaxb approach, but without need to do changes on REST server and keep the same communication/parsing logic as possible.

I have this Rest communication helper class in my Desktop version of client (irrelevant code removed)

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;

public class ServerCommunication {
...
private static final String JSON_UTF8 = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8";
    private Client client;
WebTarget webResource;
....
private ServerCommunication() {

this.client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                .register(JacksonFeature.class)
                .build();

        client.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5000);
        client.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 5000);
        webResource = client.target("https://some_ip:8181/RestServer/resources/myrestservice");

        }

public LoginResponse login(LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        WebTarget wr = webResource.path("login");


     Response response = wr.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(loginRequest, JSON_UTF8));

        LoginResponse loginResp = response.readEntity(LoginResponse.class);
        return loginResp;
    }

}
```

Classes LoginResponse and LoginRequest are as following:

```
public class LoginRequest {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public LoginRequest() {
    }

    public LoginRequest(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public LoginRequest() {

    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and response class is

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name = "")
public class LoginResponse extends BasicResponse {

    private String userId;

    public LoginResponse() {
    }

    public LoginResponse(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

So I really believe there should be simple solution how I can I use this above with "Android'ish" Rest solution and without involving jersey/jaxb/jackson?

Would be very appreciated for some hints or clear explanation how I can do and what frameworks I should do. As you see it is pretty simple in code above and I hope the same could be done in Andoriod.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, there are a few third party libraries that provide support for concurrent background threads, network caching, as well as other features that clean up networking code substantially. The first library that we looked into was Volley, an open-source library written by Google. It’s currently used in AOSP Android as well as most of Google’s first-party applications. The other is RetroFit, another open-source library written by Square.

Please follow this link you will get how to use the Retrofit library as REST client:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Comment: Would it be possible to post a small example to the code that I have posted above. It seems so simple in jersey to post request and get response with all mapping done automatically. My biggest concern (I am new and still learning) so if I just can use this jersey approach in Android when I push request and and get response like just "readEntity(..)" and also no changes is done in REST server which also serves for desktop  client.

Comment: Please follow this link you will get how to use the Retrofit library as REST client:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Comment: Thanks. I will try to run some test based on Retrofit tutor. But it would be still easier if some example would be provided. The problem is quite simple. Push class, expect class, rest done by framework. With Retrofit I still have to test what's about Jaxb annotations, . I am fine by that but just would be more than happy if could skip this trial-and-error phase :)

Comment: Well, I did some testing and was able to call REST service with Retrofit, but anyway I still do not get this Android/Retrofit framework logic (sorry, very new in Android). First of all it seems Android doesn't let you perform network operations from main thread which is from one point understandable and right way in most cases so long network operations will not "freeze" UI, but for example I want Login procedure in activity to be atomic. When user press "login" button, login GUI might be unresponsive until it gets response from login call or login timeout and then do some logic based on that.

Comment: Another my problem with Retrofit that in my app for Rest calls I want to use some "helper" Singelton class (ServerCommunication in above code) and put all my Rest calls in this class in appropriate methods. So all I have to do is to call my ServerCommunication methods with requests as pojo and expect some responses as pojo and then do some logic. With Retrofit approach it seems that I am forced to move some logic that involves response from REST service into place where actual call of REST service? Am I right? Or I am missing here something?